# Better Alternative to Telerik Draggable Panel?

Tags: asp.net, telerik

When putting a video in a Telerik Draggable Panel, when dragging the panel, on Firefox the video restart all over again because DOM is reconstructed.

They don't seem to have an answer to this. Also we can't seem to be able to control the z-index as it doesn't take into account: when moving the panel over other telerik controls, the video slips under.

So any other draggable panel that wouldn't have these annoyances ? Telerik doesn't seem to give any answer so we're afraid we're stuck and we cannot afford to wait longer.

Currently think about using Yahoo UI.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using a standard [jQuery UI draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) applied to the element?  It has many different options and appears to let you keep the current DOM element (`helper: 'original``) and allows you to set the zIndex of the draggable as well.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion will try. Also think about just using iframe as I think Iframe will always stay on top.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the RadWindow component, then you should try updating to the latest version (Q1 2010). If I remember correctly, the video problem happened because the content was hidden during move/resize operations, which caused Firefox to recreate the DOM. With the latest release, content is no longer hidden so the issue with video should be fixed.

About the z-index issue, you can check the following support articles:

http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/window/show-radwindow-above-radmenu.aspx

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/controlling-absolute-positioning-with-zindex.html